# Unexpected output of xargs

Tags: bash, sed, pipe, xargs

The statement below should print `afc abc` but it prints `abc abc` instead. I tried many times but every time same result Don't know why this happens could anyone explain and help me?

```bsh
echo abc|xargs -i{} echo $(echo {}|sed 's/b/f/g') {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does, because the command substitution is carried out by the shell before the `xargs` is even started. The `echo` in the substitution prints the literal string `{}` for `sed` to manipulate. `sed` makes no changes to it, and the result is that `xargs` sees

```
echo {} {}
```

Instead:

```
echo 'abc' | xargs -I{} bash -c 'echo "$(sed "s/b/f/g" <<<"$1")" "$1"' bash {}
```

Here, we prevent the shell from evaluating the command substitution by embedding it in an in-line script.  The script is given the command line argument (`abc`) from `xargs` and manipulates it as `"$1"`.

It would be even better to use `printf` in case you'd get the idea to replace the `a` with a dash and the other characters to something that would be interpreted as an option to `echo`:

```
echo 'abc' | xargs -I{} bash -c 'printf "%s %s\n" "$(sed "s/b/f/g" <<<"$1")" "$1"' bash {}
```

Or, without `sed`:

```
echo 'abc' | xargs -I{} bash -c 'printf "%s %s\n" "${1//b/f}" "$1"' bash {}
```

Or, you could just do it with `sed` alone (at least in this simple example):

```
echo 'abc' | sed 'h; s/b/f/g; G; s/\n/ /'
```