# use two column file as variables inside xargs command

Tags: awk, xargs

I'm trying to rename some files while learning awk / xargs. I managed a command which gives me a file with two columns, the first one being the name of the file I want to rename, the second one being the name that file should end up with.
How can I split the content of a file (preferably using programs like awk / xargs) so that I can **use each column as a variable**?

The command

```bsh
echo "foto1.JPG
foto2.JPG
foto3.JPG" | \
gawk '{ count++ }{ print $0 " " strftime("%y-%m-%d") "_" count ".JPG" }'
```

outputs

```
foto1.JPG 21-11-09_1.JPG                                                
foto2.JPG 21-11-09_2.JPG
foto3.JPG 21-11-09_3.JPG
```

which is what I want but then I don't know how to separate and use its result. I tried

```bsh
echo "foto1.JPG
foto2.JPG
foto3.JPG" | \                                                          
gawk '{ count++ }{ print $0 " " strftime("%y-%m-%d") "_" count ".JPG" }' | \
xargs -I% echo renaming $(echo % | awk '{ print $1 }') to $(echo % | awk '{ print $2 }') "..."
```

but it outputs

```
renaming foto1.JPG 21-11-09_1.JPG to ...                                                      
renaming foto2.JPG 21-11-09_2.JPG to ...
renaming foto3.JPG 21-11-09_3.JPG to ...
```

This conflicts me because

```bsh
echo renaming $(echo foo bar | awk '{ print $1 }') to $(echo foo bar | awk '{ print $2 }') "..."
```

gives me

```
renaming foo to bar ...
```

and

```bsh
echo "foto1.JPG
foto2.JPG
foto3.JPG" | \
gawk '{ count++ }{ print $0 " " strftime("%y-%m-%d") "_" count ".JPG" }' | \
xargs -I% echo this line has % in it
```

outputs

```
this line has foto1.JPG 21-11-09_1.JPG in it
this line has foto2.JPG 21-11-09_2.JPG in it
this line has foto3.JPG 21-11-09_3.JPG in it
```

I'm guessing there is something wrong with using the `%` inside the `$( ... )` statement.

Comment: Why such a convoluted process? You could use a shell loop and the built-in date function!

Comment: @Inian I want to understand better how to use pipes in general

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected output of xargs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456395/unexpected-output-of-xargs)

Comment: @muru I think it does but I'm having a hard time setting up the command, because of conflicts between both the quotes and the `$1` statement

Comment: @ffigari which should convince you to not go around inventing Rube Goldberg systems to learn pipelines

Comment: but these rube goldberg systems are fun on themselves!

Comment: `| xargs -n2 mv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no way to split the contents of the placeholder passed as part of `-I` AFAIK, you need to introduce a shell context to process the individual arguments here, i.e.

```
xargs -L1 sh -c 'renaming "$1" to "$2"' "$0"
```

The `-L1` flag handles one multiline output piped to `xargs` at a time and the `sh -c '..'` runs the contents inside, with the whole line passed to it as arguments.

---

Tangentially, you don't need a separate `counter` variable for keep tracking unique line numbers. Awk already updates the current line number in the `NR` variable, which you could use as

```bsh
gawk '{ print $0 " " strftime("%y-%m-%d") "_" NR ".JPG" }'
```